# Python comparre/evaluate list of decimals

Tags: python, decimal

I am working on an API in python that receives a list of decimals, example:

```
cutList = [3.00, 5.20, 2.50]
```

Now these decimals are cut sizes, and my API needs to test whether these cut sizes, are in/out of stock. So my API queries all current stock sizes, and will come back with something like:

```
stockList = [9.00, 3.00]
```

What I now need to do is evaluate both lists, to see if all of the values in cutList and come out of stockList

I can't just add all lists together, because that won't calculate correctly, e.g. (the below would evaluate correctly, but one 8.00 cut, would not come out of two 4.00 cuts (for example)

```
cutList = [8.00]
stockList = [4.00, 4.00]
```

But in my top example, the **3.00 + 5.20** could come from the *9.00* and the **2.50** could come from the *3.00*. So what I wan't to know/ask is the best way to get python to perform these calculations, is there any library that can do this?

I have looked at numPy but I don't really know the technical term for what I am trying to do, hence why my googling might not be returning the right information.

I could achieve this with some messy for/if statements, but I wanted to check there wasn't a cleaner (or published library) available for this.

Comment: I think this is a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: So (in essence), your problem is to find the smallest element of `stockList` that is greater than or equal to the largest element of `cutList`, subtract, remove the largest from `cutList`, and repeat?

Comment: @Linuxios yes effectively.

Comment: @crooksey: You could certainly try implementing it that way. It might not be the most efficient, but so long as the lists are small, I wouldn't even worry about it.

Comment: @Linuxios yea that was my plan if there was no other libary that already did it, cutList will have no more than 10 entries, stock list is unlikely to have any more than 5.

Comment: @crooksey: In that case, it doesn't matter how you implement it.

Comment: You're likely to run into trouble using `float` and not `decimal.Decimal` here, before you find that cuts of `0.10` and `0.20` can't be taken from `0.30`

Comment: @Linuxios: I'm not convinced that the greedy algorithm you propose is valid

Comment: @Eric: I'm not either :) -- there needs to be some kind of handling for the subtracted numbers. crooksey: please note that my proposed algorithm is a vague starting point, and WILL NOT work as is.

Comment: Well that goes without saying, I was just confirming that it could be done with a for loop along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, decided to roll my own, there was a combination of numPy libraries that I could have used (mainly numPy where), but for the size of my lists, this fits the bill.

Note, I decided to extend my demo data to include orderline numbers for the cuts required, and my stock list to return with piece_no's (stock numbers), so that when a match was found, I could setup a separate dict, noting what cuts had come from what stock rolls. It then also returns the current stock levels after all of the customers chosen cuts have been taken I don't think it's going to win me any prizes, but it works (I think). Any comments/suggestions welcome.

```
from decimal import *

# Dummy Data
cutList = [Decimal(5.22), Decimal(3.55), Decimal(3.00), Decimal(9.00)]
stockList = [Decimal(5.25), Decimal(3.55), Decimal(3.10)]
y = 156709
orderline_no = 0
cutListDec = []
stockListDec = []

for x in cutList:
    orderline_no = orderline_no +1
    cutListDec.append({'orderline_no': orderline_no, 'size': x})

for x in stockList:
    y = y +1
    stockListDec.append({'piece_no': y, 'size': x})

# Now we need to check if all cuts from cut List can be taken
# from all cuts in stockList

# Find largest array in sequence
def find_largestDec(sequence):
    """return the minimum element of sequence"""
    low = sequence[0]['size']
    for i in sequence:
        if i['size'] > low:
            low = i['size']
            line_no = i['orderline_no']
        else:
            line_no = i['orderline_no']
            low = i['size']
    return {'orderline_no': line_no, 'size': low}


# find nearest value in array
def find_nearest(arrayDict, value, cutList):
    array = []
    for item in arrayDict:
        array.append(item['size'])
    n = [abs(i-value['size']) for i in array if i >= value['size']]
    if n == []:
        return None
    else:
        idx = n.index(min(n))
        # Find piece number for matching size found
        rowFind = next((x for x in arrayDict if x['size'] == array[idx]), None)
        return {'piece_no': rowFind['piece_no'], 'size': array[idx]}

def setAllocationStatus(listItem, stockAllocation, allocationList):
    allocations.append({
            'orderline_no': listItem['orderline_no'],
            'size': listItem['size'],
            'allocation': stockAllocation
        })
    return 

allocations = []
# Run the loop for as many items in list
for _ in range(len(cutListDec)):
    # Find biggest cut from user
    largestCustomerCut = find_largestDec(cutListDec)
    # Find the nearest useable piece that matches this
    largestStockCutAllocation = find_nearest(stockListDec, largestCustomerCut, cutListDec)

    if largestStockCutAllocation != None:
        # if satisfied, it means there is a useable piece
        # subtract the size of largestCut from largestCutAllocation
        # inside the stockList dict

        # this is the stockCut that the users cut will come from
        # largestCutAllocation this will be the new size of the stock, after the users cut
        newStocksize = largestStockCutAllocation['size'] - largestCustomerCut['size']
        newSizeStockRow = {'piece_no': largestStockCutAllocation['piece_no'], 'size': newStocksize}
        # tempoary new list 
        newStockList = []
        newCutList = []
        # loop over all stock
        for x in stockListDec:
            # if stock item matches the chosen allocation
            if x['size'] == largestStockCutAllocation['size']:
                # add thew new reduced size
                newStockList.append(newSizeStockRow)
            else:
                newStockList.append(x)

        for x in cutListDec:
            if x['orderline_no'] != largestCustomerCut['orderline_no']:
                # current item does not match chosen
                # add back into list
                newCutList.append(x)
            else:
                # cut does match, mark the allocation
                setAllocationStatus(x, largestStockCutAllocation['piece_no'], allocations)
        # update original arrays
        cutListDec = newCutList
        stockListDec = newStockList
    else:
        # No pieces big enough for this cut
        newCutList = []
        for x in cutListDec:
            # remove current cut from cutList, don't check it again
            if largestCustomerCut['orderline_no'] != x['orderline_no']:
                newCutList.append(x)
            else:
                # Set allocation to be false/un-satisfied
                setAllocationStatus(x, False, allocations)
        cutListDec = newCutList

print(allocations)
print(stockListDec)
```

Tidy printout:

```
[{'orderline_no': 4, 'size': Decimal('9'), 'allocation': False},
{'orderline_no': 3, 'size': Decimal('3'), 'allocation': 156712},
{'orderline_no': 2, 'size': Decimal('3.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875'), 'allocation': 156711}, 
{'orderline_no': 1, 'size': Decimal('5.21999999999999975131004248396493494510650634765625'), 'allocation': 156710}]


[{'piece_no': 156710, 'size': Decimal('0.03000000000000024868995751604')}, 
{'piece_no': 156711, 'size': Decimal('0E-50')}, 
{'piece_no': 156712, 'size': Decimal('0.1000000000000000888178419700')}]
```